What are the excess mantras of Kanva Samhita?
The saṃhitā portion of the Śuklayajurveda known as the Vājasaneyī saṃhita has 2 different recessions - Mādhyandina & Kāṇva. Both recessions have 40 chapters but they differ in the placement of the mantras within the chapters. Most notably, the Kāṇva recession has 111 excess mantras not found in the Mādhyandina recession. Since almost every North Indian brāhmaṇas hail from the Mādhyandina śākhā, the Śuklayajurveda saṃhitā commonly encountered happens to be the Mādhyandina recession by default. So can anybody identify the excess mantras of the Kāṇva recession ?
